# all devices automatically added to team provisioning profile?

Tags: iphone, ios-provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution

i have a development provisioning profile thats managed by xcode "Team Provisioning Profile: *", and i also have an ad-hoc provisioning profile that i use for distributing builds for testing.

everytime i add a device to the ad-hoc profile (when i want to add a new beta tester), that device also gets added to my development profile. i would like my development profile to only contain developers, and the ad-hoc testing profile to only contain testers.

'automatic device provisioning' is checked in xcode organizer, i'm not sure what that does, but could it be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode automatically provisions devices you connect to your Mac to the Team Provisioning Profile. If you don't want that to happen you can un-tick the automatic provisioning option or create a new profile in the dev portal to which you can manually add a specific set of devices and use that for development builds

Comment: Where exactly is this ' automatic provisioning option' ??