# Permanently remove automatic provisioning profile managed by Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

A while ago, when I was refreshing (provisioning profiles in XCode, it kept bugging me to create a profile after every refresh.

After a few refreshes, I allowed it to create one. I assumed it would simply be a certificate signing request, but it instead created an iOS cert and provisioning profile.

However, the automatic addition of all listed devices makes it quite bad.

I have tried multiple ways to delete it, be it deleting the **cert/provisioning profile** from the Apple developer portal, and deleting the profile from Xcode, the **.mobileprovision** folder, and Keychain. None have worked; it disappears for a while, and then resurfaces.

How can I stop this profile from being generated and updated? It's conflicting with my CSR-generated profile, and causing codesign errors.

There was apparently an automatic provisioning option you could untick, but I can't find it. [all devices automatically added to team provisioning profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598883/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on xcode build settings. You should only choose your team in general preferences tab. Then go to build settings tab and choose the right provisioning profile under "code signing" section. It should fix the issue, if it doesn't remove certificates from keychain and re-download/install the right certificate from developer center.

Comment: The issue was that the certificates were being generated in the team. Anyways, like you said, I've resorted to downloading the certificates I want from the Apple developer center. I also no longer use the machine that originally created these provisioning profiles through Xcode.

Comment: If you want to resolve your codesign error, you must check in your keychain which developer / distribution certificate is installed on your machine. One you found the certificates installed on your machine, go to developer-center and create a new developer / distribution provisioning profile, download it, drag&drop into xcode and chose it from build settings panel on your project settings.

Comment: Make sure that your keychain has the private password for the development/production certificate. If the certificate in "my certificate" section in the keychain does not have the disclosure arrow on the side, that certificate is not valid. In this You must create a new certificate through developer center

Answer (score 0):

I was getting stumped by this too; I wanted to use my own provisioning profile because it was associated with an explicit App ID I needed to enable push notifications, but Apple kept on using a wildcard `XC: com.myapp.*` profile instead. Eventually the solution that worked for me was to use the [developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/iphone) to change the auto-generated profile to use my explicit App ID, then re-download and install. I never managed to remove the auto-generated profile, but I made it work for me and it solved my problem.

Comment: where can we find "change the auto-generated profile to use my explicit App ID" in developer portal?

Comment: @mohsinj - visit the Developer Portal in a browser, find the auto-generated provisioning profile that was uploaded by Xcode, and edit the profile to use your desired App ID.